# Cannot Upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Here is the problem in a nutshell:

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2. It has SSIS packages deployed to it that precede my hiring, so I do not know when they were created or on what platform.

I wrote some SSIS packages in Visual Studio 2013 SSDT and they cannot be deployed to the 2008 R2 SP2 instance - VS gives me an error saying it's incompatible.

So, we want to upgrade the existing instance, but are running into problems.  First, we are ABLE to upgrade the SSIS packages using SSMS' wizard (on the 2008 R2 instance).  However, after doing so, the SQL Server 2014 Upgrade Advisor states that these packages have not been upgraded. This seems axiomatic because how can a 2008 SSMS instance upgrade SSIS packages beyond itself?

Regardless, I am unable to connect to the SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Integration Services using SSMS 2014 - it says "Access Denied". There was some Microsoft documentation detailing the modification of the MsDTSSrvr.ini.xml file to allow for the connection, but it doesn't work.

So, at the end of the day, the SQL Server 2014 Upgrade Advisor states there are essentially two problems with the existing packages: their connection strings are wrong - and their variables are missing. My plan was to export all of the packages, upgrade them with SSDT, then delete them from the 2008 instance - upgrade the instance to 2014, and then deploy the upgraded packages. However, there are 8 SSIS packages in the MSDB that cannot be deleted:

```
PerfCountersCollect, PerfCoutnersUpload, 
QueryActivityCollect, QueryActivityUpload, 
SqlTraceCollect, SqlTraceUpload, 
TSqlQueryCollect, TSqlQueryUpload
```

It says that deleting them violates a FK constraint within the MSDB database.

Please help - I just want to export the packages, upgrade the instance, upgrade the packages, and finally deploy them to the upgraded instance, but nothing is working.  Thanks in advance and I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this thread, but I didn't know where to put it.

Comment: I would look closely at the FK that would be violated by deleting the packages.  I've never heard of an FK that relies on a package.   Maybe the FK can be dropped since you want to drop the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved.  The errors that were displayed were essentially boogeymen.  The problem was that the installation ISO that we had was for an evaluation version of SQL 2014, yet we have a licensed Standard version in production.  After getting the correct ISO, the upgrade succeeded without any problems.